# Python 3 tkinter: How to use .after() on canvas graphics?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to animate a circle that moves over time but i do not know how to use `.after()` on `Canvas` to add a delay before the circle changes position each time. Does anyone know how to do this?
Thanks.

my code (i have put a `.sleep()` where i would like the delay to be):

```
from tkinter import *
import time
root = Tk()

c = Canvas(root, width = 500, height = 500)
c.pack()

oval = c.create_oval(0, 0, 0, 0)
for x in range(2, 50, 5):
    time.sleep(0.1)
    c.delete(oval)
    oval = c.create_oval(x+50, x+50, x+50, x+50)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple example of using `.after`, derived from your code. As you can see, the `.after` method needs to be supplied a function to call after the specified delay, so you need to wrap your changes in a function.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width = 500, height = 500)
canvas.pack()
radius = 10
bbox = (-radius, -radius, radius, radius)
oval = canvas.create_oval(*bbox)

def move_oval():
    canvas.move(oval, 1, 1)
    canvas.after(20, move_oval)

# Start moving!
move_oval()

root.mainloop()
```

If you'd like to see a more complex example, take a look at [tk_orbit.py](https://gist.github.com/PM2Ring/d7878c904df8da838f76dc4a15c6c746).